# Installing Tiger on an iBook G4 A1134 running Leopard

Tags: macos, powerpc, downgrade, ibook

I have recently acquired an iBook G4 to run a specific software for research. The iBook currently has Leopard installed but the software I want to run doesn't work since the iBook doesn't have the classic environment. Because of this, I'm trying to downgrade to Tiger or Panther but I don't have installation disks. I have been trying to follow the USB stick methods but these aren't working. The iBook doesn't show the USB when you boot holding the option key. I'm not sure if this means there is some problem with the disk image I'm using. I have tried .dmg and .iso. Is there some recommended place to download the disk images? Is it even possible to install these older systems using this method?

Comment: Old Macs are tough to boot from USB stick. You really need the CD. There's a guide here on USB boot but idk which models it will work on, nor what format the USB will need. https://www.macintoshrepository.org/articles/115-how-to-boot-ppc-powermacs-g3-g4-g5-from-a-usb-stick-or-drive- Let us know how it goes.

Comment: There are some other guides which describe how to partition the USB which I've tried to no avail. I will be trying over the coming weekend and likely the coming weeks and I'll edit the question if I manage to find a working method.

Comment: @Tetsujin, related question, is it possible to burn the install discs from some downloaded .dmg/.iso? Possibly using the iBook to ensure the correct format etc. I have avoided this possibility just because I don't want to buy a pack of disks that I'll never use again but if it provided a solution I would definitely bite the bullet and do it.

Comment: You'd have to find someone that has imaged them & posted online - which isn't strictly 'legal' as each OS X in those days was quite a pricey purchase. https://lowendmac.com/2009/tips-for-installing-or-reinstalling-mac-os-x-10-4-tiger/ has a guide.

Comment: I don't think I strictly need OSX, would it be simpler, perhaps, to just install OS9? Is it even possible on this model of iBook?

Comment: If it's this one, then no - https://everymac.com/systems/apple/ibook/specs/ibook_g4_1.42_14.html